# 'createConnection' is deprecated

Tags: node.js, typescript, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I am creating my first application in Node with Graphql, and for now I have only written this code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
const express = require('express');
import { Express } from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from 'apollo-server-core';
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql';
import { ActivityResolver } from './resolvers/activity';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

const main = async () => {
    // Setup database connection
    const conn = await createConnection({
        type: 'postgres',
        database: 'deliveryapi',
        entities: [],
        logging: true,
        synchronize: true,
        username: process.env.USERNAME || 'postgres', 
        password: process.env.PASSWORD || 'Juventus',
        port: 5432,
    });

    // Create express application for GraphQL server
    const apollo: ApolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [ActivityResolver],
            validate: false,
        }),
        plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()],
    })
    const app: Express = express();

    // All application required varibles
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    // Middleware and routes
    await apollo.start();
    apollo.applyMiddleware({ app });
    app.use(express.json());
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.send("Hello World")});

    // Start server
    app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT} and connected to database`)});

}

main().catch(err => {console.error("Error: ", err)});
```

The problem is that, in VSCode there is a problem in this line: `import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';`. It is deleted and it says that it is deprecated, and I can't understand why, an if that affect the code. I am using Typescript.

Can someone explain please? Thank you

Comment: See my answer below. Please update the tags. It has nothing to do with `graphql` and your question is related to `typeorm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version `0.3.0` of `typeorm`, `createConnection` is deprecated in favour of the new `DataSoure` API. See the Changelog for `0.3.0` https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Also have a look at: https://typeorm.io/data-source

Answer (score 1):

As I was playing a bit with typeORM, just found out that you can place this into your `index.ts` file

```js
import { AppDataSource } from "./data-source";
AppDataSource.initialize().then(() => {
console.log("Data Source has been initialized!");}).catch((err) => {
console.error("Error during Data Source initialization", err);});
```